# Unable to resolve MVC view when using Spring and Intellj

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

Having a confusing issue that may be entirely due to inexperience with both Spring and/or Intellj, but after searching across the internet and SO and the lot, was having no luck on how to fix so here goes.

In a nutshell, I have a sample application that I'm working on to gain some experience with Spring/Hibernate/Maven. It works fine (loads pages as expected, etc...), but in the code, I have a ton of flags for the IDE not able to resolve MVC views, which I can't see as to why this would be the case.

The setup is web.xmlless, using an entirely Java setup with the following Listener configuration as so.

```
@Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }
```

and here one example of code where it flags that it cannot resolve the MVC view

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }
```

with userslist being the offending view not being found.

While I'm fairly certain that it's not a missing Spring plugin, the pom.xml has the following spring components, using version 4.2.5

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also using the latest version of IntellJ, 2016.2.4 that is registered.

Comment: So your code is working but you are uneasy about IntelliJ's warnings?

Comment: @Mechkov effectively yes that's a good way of summing it up. It may be nothing of course, but I rather have confirmation with citation as to why instead of finding it biting me in the ass down the road.

Comment: Here is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76235738/7560349

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution (I have to write an answer because of the screenshot):
You did not configure the facet for your module. 
Open the Project Structure Dialog 
go to the Modules entry on the left and add the Spring facet to it.
If you have done this you can add your spring configurations.
[image: project structure dialog]

Idea should have notified you that there are unregistered Spring configs (something like this)

Comment: So just gave that a try but sadly no dice. It offered three java files to choose from, but adding them and rebooting tomcat has done next to nothing regarding the issue occurring.

Comment: Rebooting tomcat has no effect here because we are 'just' talking about an IDE feature. Do you have one 'main' config file that includes the other ones? If you add all three (A, B, C) and A includes B and C, the problem might be that you now have duplicated (from IntelliJ's POV) informations and another warning. Another possible problem could be that IntelliJ cannot match `viewname` to `WEB-INF/viewname.jsp`. Currently I have no 'raw' Spring MVC project on hand to verify this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, one possible cause for this issue could be the wrong **Web Resource Directory**. Go to **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Modules** -> On the left side **Web** -> **Web Resource Directories** below configure the path to your web resource directory

Comment: This worked for me. Answer bookmarked! Thanks @Jason

Comment: This is a workaround for a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After spending around 4 hours on this, I found that this is an Intellij bug that is reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186130?_ga=2.164067640.669602953.1596628724-384664884.1564859093).

The workaround is to configure view resolver like this:

```
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/pages/", ".jsp");
}
```

Comment: Oddly IDEA Ultimate 2020.2 did this until I told it to invalidate caches and restart. So, I'm seeing the bug fixed in 2021.1 beta, but I worked around it without that. I did tell the module to add thymeleaf which didn't appear to do anything before invalidate and restarting.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue occurs becouse Itellij does not properly recognize the ViewResolver Bean. Try changing the configuration of viewResolver to something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.app")

public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    public void configureDefaultServerletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please mention suggested configurations or resolver() method for html static page ( If that is present in resource/static directory).

Answer (score 0):

I had the `@Configuration` class extend a base abstract class. The base abstract class did create the `FreeMarkerConfigurer` and `FreeMarkerViewResolver` objects.

Moving the creation of `FreeMarkerConfigurer` and `FreeMarkerViewResolver` from the abstract class to the class with the `@Configuration` annotation solved the problem that IntelliJ couldn't find my *freemarker* template/views.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.5
 

com.codepresso
controllerexercise
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
controllerexercise
controllerexercise

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Maybe you haven't added TEMPLATE ENGINES: Thymeleaf so there may be an error

Comment: Please format the text above so anybody can read it good.