# Intellij showing cannot resolve MVC view even though spring boot application is running fine

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

After intializing the spring application with Spring Web.
I created Login Controller class as below and create static html files in `resources/static` folder

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "index.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping("login")
    public String gotoLoginPage( ) {
        return "login.html";
    }
}
```

My application is running fine. But, intelliJ is showing "Cannot resolve MVC view index.html" and "Cannot resolve MVC view login.html".

I tried but am not able to resolve the intelliJ warning.

Tried lot of debugging and changing html file paths.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245083/2960034

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA, a possible reason for the problem is an incorrect Web Resource Directory. To fix it:

1. Click **File** > **Project Structure** > **Modules**
2. Click **Web**
3. Under **Web Resource Directories** click '**+**' to add the missing resource directory (For me, the resource directory is 'webapp' which contains my .jsp and asset files)
4. Click **OK** to save your changes.

See attached image for more info:
[image]